# What should I do if client request my staff personal phone number?

Tags: management, communication, customer-service

I am doing Software Development and sometimes we have mis-developments. 
Some customers request that I give the personal phone number of my staff members to do the claim directly.

What should I do? or How should I deal with that customer?

What will be the best solution for a win-win situation in the above case?

If you have any ideas, please let me know and it would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Why do they need the personal phone number? What's wrong with the business phone or office extension of your staff?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "do claim directly". I also don't get what your actual question here is. Are you asking us if you should give your employee's personal number? Or do you want to know how to tell the customer that you cannot give the personal number? Also, as Brandin points out, it is not clear why they insist on a personal phone number.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. In fact, customers said me to give his(my staff) number because they want to claim for his development-miss.

But I'd never thought, why they insist to get a personal phone as Brandin point out. So, I couldn't answer well to my customer.  Thanks to Brandin, from now, I will persuade my customers to call from office business phone.

Comment: Even so, your setup sounds rather strange. A customer should file claims against the project, or maybe the company, not against individual developers.

Comment: Why the close votes? The question may not be crystal-clear, but the situation of a client attempting to bypass a company's internal processes is a legitimate problem.

Comment: Maybe they just want to know how to contact that employee personally, not really "personal phone." I.e., just tell them how to get in touch directly with that person.

Comment: Yes, Brandin. I would like to say "client want to contact employee personally". Sorry for my English, since I'm not native.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by asking the client why they want personal phone numbers. Is it because they prefer the services of a specific employee of yours? Is it because the 'generic' business phone is unresponsive?

Generally, there is no obvious upside to your company or your employees in clients having direct numbers. The upside pretty much belongs to the client alone, who can now bypass your company-internal routines and perhaps even socially pressure your employees into additional og possibly even free services.

The only win-win I see is sitting down with the client and hearing their concerns and afterwards actually addressing them. Perhaps they really do need a direct contact 24/7 - for which your company should get paid and the named employee probably compensated.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is simple.. you tell the client "No"

Personal phones are just that *personal* and there is no good reason to give that out to clients, who has someone's personal number is up to the individual not their boss or company. I apologize if I'm being a bit blunt or harsh here but having been in the position where a boss gave out my personal number to a client (and didn't even tell me!) who then called me up on Christmas Eve (company was on Christmas shutdown). I was polite enough to the client but I went utterly *ballistic* at my boss, it was absolutely unacceptable.